# The word that describes a feeling of confusion/second guessing

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions, thought

It's like the feeling you get when you have second thoughts or second guess yourself. Not really suspicious, but more with a self reflection/introspection tone.

As I thought more about what she said, I began to feel ___. Why didn't I catch her cues the first time?
When I ran over the speech again, I felt ___. Why was it so difficult for me to accept what he wrote?
Also, what are some verbal cues that can describe this feeling?

Comment: regretful, lost, dejected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two suggestions that seem to fit into your context. “I began to feel *uneasy* ... I felt *disquieted*”.

If the last sentence is part of your question and means that you are looking for verbal cues, you might listen for phrases containing “*anxious*“, “*concerned*”, “*I wonder ...*”, “*worried*”, “*ill-at-ease*”. These are all pointers to unease and disquiet in the mind of the speaker.

I do not repeat easily-found dictionary definitions here.